# Не работает text-overflow

Tags: css

Не работает `text-overflow`. Каким образом решается данная проблема?

```css
    .item {
        padding: 10px 10px;
        border-top: 1px solid #DCDCDC;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #DCDCDC;
        background: #F7F7F7;
        margin-bottom: 5px;
        position: relative;
    }

    #description {
        color: black;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="item">
        <a href="">Заголовок</a>
        <div id="description">
            Задает все свойства фона элемента страницы в один прием. Заменяет собой атрибуты background-attachment, background-color, background-image, background-position и background-repeat.
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

С помощью двух данных свойств можно "починить" text-overflow.

- `white-space: nowrap` - запрещаем делать перенос на другую строку.
- `overflow: hidden` - непосредственно скрываем текст, выходящий за рамки контейнера, для того чтобы в силу вступило свойство text-overflow.

```css
.search_page_item {
  padding: 10px 10px;
  border-top: 1px solid #DCDCDC;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #DCDCDC;
  background: #F7F7F7;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  position: relative;
}

#description {
  color: black;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="search_page_item">
  <a href=""/>Заголовок</a>
  <div id="description">
    Задает все свойства фона элемента страницы в один прием. Заменяет собой атрибуты background-attachment, background-color, background-image, background-position и background-repeat.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: спасибо огромное, друг:)

Comment: И еще небольшое дополнение - должен быть inline